# Call a javascript function throught URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with tabs, where each tab is in fact in the same table with an atribute that show it or not. Then a javascript function would change the attribute when you press on the tab.

The function is something like this:

```
function showHide(ID) {
 switch (ID) {
   case 'main':
     document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('abstracts').style.display = 'none';
     break;
   case 'abstracts':
     document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('abstracts').style.display = 'block';
     break;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Then, the title of the tab is something like

```
<a href="" onclick="showHide('main');return false;">Main</a>
```

and the tab is

```
<tr id="main"> ... </tr>
```

The thing is that I would like to be able to have a URL for a tab, for example http://mypage.com#main or something like that, so when I enter to that URL, the tab main is focussed.

Is that possible?

Comment: yes, read the hash on page load....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of your page or `window.onload`, read the hash and call your method.

```
(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    showHide(hash);
}());
```

and if you want the url to change, you probably want to remove the `return false`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashchange event listener here. 
eg :window.addEventListener("hashchange", doThisWhenTheHashChanges, false);